# Django query, annotate latest childs value

Tags: django, annotate

Is it possible to annotate value of last child? There is model  StoreItem, that has relation has many to model Movement:

```
StoreItem.objects.last().movements.last().total_count # => 32
```

I need something like:

```
StoreItem.objects.annotate(total_count_of_last_movement=...??...)
```

Thank you!

Comment: what do you want to achieve? `last()` only returns one object, you can `annotate` only over a QuerySet.

Comment: 'StoreItem' for example has 10 'Movement', I need only value of last movement `total_count`

so if: `StoreItem.objects.last().movements.last().total_count` => `32`

then when i annotate it like

`store_items = StoreItem.objects.annotate(total_count_of_last_movement=...??...)` then

`stole_items.last().total_count_of_last_movement` => `32`.

What must be in `...??...`. Thank you for so fast reply! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your last comment, you don't need to aggregate.

Assuming your models are something like:

```
class Movement(models.Model):
    ...
    store_item = models.ForeignKey(StoreItem, ..., related_name='movements')
    total_count = models.IntegerField(...)

class StoreItem(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.TextField(...)
```

you just need to add an attribute to the `StoreItem` model:

```
class StoreItem(models.Model):
    ...
    title = models.TextField(...)

    @property
    def last_movement_total_count(self):
        if self.movements is not None and self.movements.count() > 0:
            return self.movements.last().total_count
        return None # or -1 or something that tells that there are no movements
```

this way you can do:

```
store_item = StoreItem.objects.last() # or get or whatever you need
last_movement_total_count = store_item.last_movement_total_count
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! It's something new for me :)

Comment: glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question, but here is my suggestion:

Since you want the `StoreItem` set, you can try:

```
last_movement_total_count = StoreItem.objects.last().movements.last().total_count
```

then:

```
store_items_with_count = StoreItem.objects.filter(movement__total_count=last_movement_total_count)
```

here, `store_items_with_count` holds all the `StoreItems` which at least one `movement` has a `total_count` value of `last_movement_total_count`, then

```
store_items_with_count.last() # the last StoreItem
```

But, if you want the `StoreItem` of the last movement, it's simplier:

```
last_store_item = Movement.objects.last().store_item
```

Hope that this helps, if not, please specify your models and what do you want to get at the end.

Comment: I trying to make one query, which gives me list of objects `StoreItem` ,  objects will have all attributes from table 'store_itrems'(id, title, ect.) AND one "additional" attribute - some_value_of_last_movement, which takes value of last movement of StoreItem object. Is it possible to do with `annotate`. Thank you.